# Can blender separate a sculpt mesh like zbrush?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt, zbrush

I want to seperate a sculpted mesh and sculpt the on it without effecting the other mesh.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can **Mask** the part of the mesh you want to separate

[image]

and then choose the **Mask -> Mask Slice to New Object** menu option

[image]

Which will give you two new objects (the Blender pseudo-equivalent of SubTools).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Omg thank you 